# How was Michael Douglas' apparent facelift achieved in "Behind the Candelabra"?

Tags: effects, make-up, behind-the-candelabra

Michael Douglas, playing Liberace, has a facelift partway through the HBO movie. His skin is noticeably tighter and smoother afterwards. How was the effect achieved?

Comment: A mix of botox and make-up/prosthetics?

Answer (score 2):

**Make-up, possibly with prosthetics**

From this interview with [Vulture](http://www.vulture.com/2013/05/michael-douglas-on-liberace.html) about playing the role:

> In his long, over 40-year career—playing ­everything from Gordon Gekko, a titan of Wall Street (for which he won the Academy Award for Best Actor), to the philandering husband in Fatal ­Attraction to a ­compromised cop in Basic Instinct to a pot-smoking novelist in Wonder Boys—**Douglas has always been a Zeitgeist-y embodiment of the modern man. Which means he has never worn prosthetics in a movie,** let alone a rhinestone-encrusted floor-length fur cape decorated with sequins. ***“I was the girl on this movie! The hair and makeup for Liberace took two and a half hours,”* Douglas said. *“I’ve never done elaborate hair and makeup before.*** Up until now, my entire career has been contemporary.”